# How to override Source Maps for Vue.js Client Scripts in Visual Studio 2019 for the Debugger to stop at breakpoints?

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, source-maps

I am learning `Vue`. Recently I found out that there is a bug in `Visual Studio` that effectively prevents the debugger from stopping at breakpoints of client scripts (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/520247/vue-app-in-vs-2019-cannot-debug-javascript-code.html).

I figured out that as I wrote here: [Debugging Vue.js app in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549629/debugging-vue-js-app-in-visual-studio-2017/59673010#59673010), following the recipe from https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/vuejs-cli, it is possible to overcome this problem in `Visual Studio Code` by overriding `Source Map` paths.

Let's consider the following project structure:

[image]

To resolve the `Source Maps` properly for the debugging, I would need the following `launch.json` file in `Visual Studio Code`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Node",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\source\\server\\server.js",
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "vuejs: chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/source/client/src",
            "breakOnLoad": true,
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///*": "*",
                "webpack:///./~/*": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/*"
            }
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Vue",
            "configurations": [
                "Node",
                "vuejs: chrome"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With the following `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "label": "build",
        "command": "npm",
        "args": ["run", "build"],
        "type": "shell"
    }]
}
```

Where the build task itself is defined in `package.json` and consists the following command:

```
"build": "cd source/client && vue-cli-service build"
```

In `Visual Studio` I can mirror it by setting the appropriate properties:

[image]

[image]

However I would also need to override the `Source Map` paths somehow, the question is how to mirror the `sourceMapPathOverrides` `Visual Studio Code` option in `Visual Studio 2019`?

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/source/client/src",
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
    "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
    "webpack:///*": "*",
    "webpack:///./~/*": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/*"
```